# Reading objects from file Java

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize an object and then deserialize from the file. As of right now the serialize works (or it reports it works when run). For some reason when I am trying to deserialize it, it reports a StreamCorruptedException.
This is the reported stack trace:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A0A5072
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at Assignment8.main(Assignment8.java:201)
```

After looking on the web and trying to find examples, this was what I believe I would need to do

```
System.out.print("Please enter a file name to read:\n");
             filename = stdin.readLine().trim();

             try{                  
               FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
               ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);//line 201
               while(true){
                   try{
                       Project proj1 = (Project) in1.readObject();
                       ArrayList<Project> pla = new ArrayList<Project>();
                       pla.add(proj1);
                       for(Project proj:pla){
                           String nam = proj.getName();
                           String loc = proj.getLocation();
                           int num = proj.getNumber();
                           double bud = proj.getFund();
                           manage1.addProject(nam, loc, num, bud);
                       }
                   }catch(EOFException e){
                       System.out.println(filename+ " was read");
                       in1.close();
                       break;
                   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

                   }

               }
             }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
               System.out.println(filename+" was not found");
             }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("io exception deserislaing");
             }
             break;
```

I am using the ArrayList in order to hold the objects that are read from the file before I add them to my main ProjectManagement array. The file I am reading from is a .dat file. Could this be possibly causing my error? Thanks :)

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: It is a file that my professor has created in our submission site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use [`ObjectInputStream.readObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) to fetch your serialized object from the file.  Did you also use [`ObjectOutputStrem.writeObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)) to originally write your object to the file?

It is common to see this `StreamCorruptedException` when the methods you use to read and write are not inverses of each other.

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem, was writing using FileWriter.